# How to exit debug mode in eclipse and clear earlier debug records

Tags: java

I know there is `Java` box on the right top corner in eclipse. But it doesn't actually exit debug mode. Eclipse still shows that "running". I mean how to exit debug mode and then can click "debug as java application" and program stops at the first breakpoint again.

**EDIT:**
I mean two times debugging because something hasn't been watched in the first time. So I want to debug again from the beginning of the program. In the first time, program stops at line 3. In the second time, when I press F8, program can stop at line1(breakpoint). But when I click `java`, eclipse doesn't really exit debug mode in the first time.

```
  public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("hello"); // line 1, breakpoint
            System.out.println(""); // line 2
        } // line 3
  }
```

Comment: You want to clear breakpoints?  Or if you want to `stop` the process click on the red square box in the console window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply clicking on Java view doesnt exit the debug mode.

[image: Debug Mode]

In this dialog you will see the stop button (first row) if current process in running. Just stop it.

Comment: Is there a window for watching variable?For example :Input a to see value of variable a, input b to see value of variable of b.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html
Please check this link out. It covers many eclipse debugging tricks.